# Do I need to buy a different PSU?

Tags: power-supply, gpu, cable

I recently bought a 750W power supply with intent of using it for my 3070 gpu. When I installed it I noticed that the only cables left remaining where the ones in the photo below. Clearly I messed up. Can I buy adapters for these or do I need to buy a whole new PSU?

Relevant Equipment Used

1. Gpu MSI Gaming GeForce RTX 3070 LHR... [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B097M7MW9M?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B097M7MW9M)
2. PSU ARESGAME 750W Power Supply Semi... [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08JM12SQ5?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JM12SQ5)

Comment: your links are broken, and seem to point to a different location than their text indicates.

Comment: @FrankThomas: SuperUser itself rewrites Amazon links for affiliate tracking, so your ad blocker (hosts file?) probably doesn't like it. They still point to the same product IDs.